# User to set their real location on map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wonder if anyone has done this or can point me in the right direction to do it using Google Maps API and preferably PHP and JS.

I want to be able to get a user's address and Post/ZIP code, then display a map showing their location.

Because of the nature of postcodes in the UK, the 'actual' location could be some way away from what is shown. (Eg In Wales - the postcode of a golf club can cover about 2 square miles which is criss-crossed with small roads and lanes).

I then want the user to be able to drag the pointer - or some other method - and point to their real location on the map - and this point (lat/long) to be passed back to my code.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Basic concept:

1. Geocode the data you have to a LatLng value: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder
2. Using the LatLng from step 1, place a draggable marker on the map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker
3. Listen to the `dragend` event on the marker to get the new LatLng.

Applicable samples:

- [Geocoding](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)
- [Draggable marker](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to get the lat and lng when a user clicks on my Google map:

```
  //capture lat and lng when user clicks on map
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
     var lat = event.latLng.lat();
     var lng = event.latLng.lng();
     $("#lat").val(lat);
     $("#lng").val(lng);
     //console.log("Lat: "+ event.latLng.lat() +"Lng: "+ event.latLng.lng());    
  });
```

And here is the JQuery I use to submit the data to the server to be added into a db (there is a form where a user can create a few more variables):

```
    //when user clicks submit button on form, use ajax/json to send info to db
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var lat = $("#lat").val();
        var lng = $("#lng").val();
        var type = $("#type").val();
        var des = $("#des").val();
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "DB_addProblem.php",
              data: "lat="+ lat + "&lng="+ lng + "&type="+ type + "&des="+ des
        }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Submited: " + msg + "!!!");
        });
     });
```

Comment: Andrew...I would love to but apparently i havent got enough 'reputation' yet to be able to do that. Sorry